# "it didn't sent the messages"?

Tags: past-tense, negation, do-support

Which one is correct?

> it didn't sent the messages

OR:

> it didn't send the messages

Comment: the latter (for example http://www.edufind.com/english-grammar/simple-past-tense/)

Comment: The basic principle is *only one verb is inflected for tense* in a clause. You've already got ***do = did***, so ***send*** is just an (unmarked) infinitive form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you negate a sentence by using do or did, you should use the whole verb. Since *to send* is the whole verb, you should use *It didn't send the messages*.

Comment: Plus, he used the simple past with " I didn't", so logically the verb who precede is in the infinitive form.